# Why does isNaN() ignore letters in between numbers?

Tags: javascript

For example, `isNaN("1e0")` returns `false`, but `isNaN("10e")` returns `true`. Why?

Sorry if this is a dupe; I looked through similar questions but found no answer.

Comment: "1e0" means 1*10^0, it is a valid number. It is not just "a letter between number" but a part of the number like + and - signals. "10e" is lacking the exponent, thus not a number.

Comment: Run `const a = 1e0; console.log(a);` What do you get?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Ahh smart. I'm a noob; thank you!